# Powershell - Start Process on Different Drive from Batch CMD

Tags: batch, powershell, process, cmd.exe, call

Problem:
From the CMD or Batchfile, calling powershell and starting a process from a different drive or the -FilePath is failing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Use the following syntax, **with Single Quotes Only** (double quotes do not work)-

```
powershell start-process -FilePath 'E:\Trunk Monkey\Utilities\SkypePortable\SkypePortable.exe'
```

Details:
I was having no luck with other parameters, to include...

```
powershell -Command "& {}
```

as listed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the path to your executable:

```
powershell -Command "& { Start-Process -FilePath 'E:\Trunk Monkey\Utilities\SkypePortable\SkypePortable.exe' }"
```

Comment: Excellent. While this was intended to be a KB type question, you provided an answer to my example question. Thanks!